# Correct symbols in XML eBay API request

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I am trying to get a product through eBay API using this XML request:

```
<aspectFilter>
    <aspectName>Genre</aspectName>
    <aspectValueName>Comedy & Spoken Word</aspectValueName>
</aspectFilter>
```

But I receive following error in response:

```
<errorMessage xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
   <error>
      <errorId>2030</errorId>
      <domain>CoreRuntime</domain>
      <severity>Error</severity>
      <category>System</category>
      <message>Internal error: [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
         at javax.xml.stream.SerializableLocation@1b0a1b0a</message>
      <subdomain>System</subdomain>
      <parameter name="Param1">[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32) (missing name?)
         at javax.xml.stream.SerializableLocation@1b0a1b0a</parameter>
   </error>
</errorMessage>
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the special character `&` which is causing the error. eBay system doesn't accept special character as inpit so you should convert to html code, so `&` should be passed as `&#38;`. Then your request should look like this

```
<aspectFilter>
    <aspectName>Genre</aspectName>
    <aspectValueName>Comedy &#38; Spoken Word</aspectValueName>
</aspectFilter>
```